# How to get default installation directory for IBM MQ in linux and unix?

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

`I have used MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH in linux

when i execute above in the path */opt/mqm/bin* via root  it cannot display nothing but when i execute it in the path */opt/mqm/samp/bin* it displays MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH .. before i should execute crtmqenv -p command

So what a solution to get installation path of IBM MQ?

Comment: when i execute **$MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQ v7.1 and higher support multiple installations on the same server.  The command `setmqenv` when sourced will setup some environment variables to allow you to use a specific installation.  One of the variables that is set by `setmqenv` is `$MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH`.  You can display the value of this variable with the command `echo $MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH`.

```
$ echo $MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH
/opt/mqm
```

If the installation has been setup as default using the `setmqinst` command, then various symlinks will be created under `/usr/bin` pointed back to the mq installation directory.  You can display the installation directory by running the `/usr/bin/dspmqver` command and looking for `InstPath` in the output.

You can also directly call the command `dspmqver -f 128` to have it return just the installation path:

```
InstPath:    /opt/mqm
```

If the install is not setup as the default install and you do not know which directory MQ is installed in you can look at the `/etc/opt/mqm/mqinst.ini` file which will have a stanza for each installation on the server.  The installation path is listed after `FilePath=` under each `Installation` stanza.

```
$ cat /etc/opt/mqm/mqinst.ini
Installation:
   Name=Installation1
   Description=
   Identifier=1
   FilePath=/opt/mqm
```

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is that you can use `dspmqver -f 128` to have it return just the installation path.

Comment: @RobParker thank you for the tip, I have updated the answer with this command as well.